# Swift: Nested optionals in a single guard statement

Tags: swift, option-type

I am trying to guard a conversion from string to Float to Int:

```
guard let v = Int (Float("x")) else {
    return -1
}
```

The swift 3 compiler complains:

> value of optional type 'Float?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Adding "?" does not help, though. And "!" would be wrong here, wouldn't it?

Is it possible to solve this, without having to use two lines or two guard statements?

Comment: You should ***not*** use `-1` as a sentinel value in Swift. That's the exact point of Optionals!

Comment: Haha, thanks for pointing that out, even though it was not part of my question :)

Comment: By two lines you mean: `guard let f = Float("x"), let v = Int(f) else {`

Comment: ^ I would do this if I had a need for the intermediate (such as for error logging), but if I only care about the end result, I would recommend `map` instead

Comment: Oh, nevermind.  That doesn't work because `Int(f)` doesn't return an optional.

Comment: You could always use `case let` @vacawama

Comment: Well if you really wanted to make it work, you could shoe horn it into: `Optional(Int(f))` :p But yeah, don't do that

Comment: Right @Hamish: `guard let f = Float("3.2"), case let v = Int(f) else {`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Optional has a [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) function made just for this:

```
guard let v = Float("x").map(Int.init) else {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I knew about `map` but not about this way of applying it - I only considered it for Array so far. Swift keeps surprising me and I'm glad asked.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann `flatMap` and `map` are available on types that are Monads. Collections are monads, as is Optional. So you can map and flatMap them :)

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann Check this out: http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/593ec74a536a26203718f429

Comment: just to be sure: `Int.init` is identical to `Int($0)`. Though the first one is you passing a function that takes a single parameter the 2nd one is you passing a closure with the parameter?

Comment: @Honey If you went the `Int($0)` route, it would have to be this: `.map({ Int($0) })`, because trailing closures cannot appear in `guard let` statements. It's messier

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with one `guard` statement with an intermediate variable:

```
guard let f = Float("x"), case let v = Int(f) else {
    return
}
```

Note:  The `case` is there as a workaround for the fact that `Int(f)` does not return an optional value.  (Thanks for the idea, @Hamish)

Comment: Not sure you need the 'case' here.

Comment: @MarqueIV, the `case` is a workaround because `Int(f)` is NOT optional.  Another way to workaround that would have been `guard let f = Float(str), let v = Optional(Int(f)) else { return }`.

Comment: Whoa!  Didn't know that!  Glad I posted because you're right... I didn't notice it wasn't an optional and this solves a problem I've had for that exact same case.  Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: @MarqueIV, thanks for asking and not just assuming I'm an idiot ;-).  In fact, I learned this from Hamish in the comments under the original question.

Comment: Technically I didn't ask! ;)  Still, at least I said 'not sure'. lol